# Serving Directory and FIles as a File manager - ExpressJS

Tags: apache, nginx, express

Is it possible to server files and directories as some sort of file manager, as is possible in  Apacke or Nginx?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `st` module will do this. https://github.com/isaacs/st

Answer (score 0):

I have used http-server. It is very simple and easy to use.

https://github.com/nodeapps/http-server